# What do you mean by 'spark somebody up'?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I have searched throughout the internet to find the real meaning but was at loss.

Comment: Next time, add [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=spark+up&ls=a) to the places you search :^) It's a great site for questions like this one.

Comment: Just checked and found that spark up is there. I am not asking 'the meaning of spark up', I am asking 'spark somebody up'.

Comment: I'm inclined to think the two are related. If "spark up" is roughly equivalent "light up", then I'd reckon that to "spark someone up" would mean to offer them a light. However, you've not offered any additional context other than the title of your question, so I wouldn't bet my mortgage on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verb *spark* can be used to mean *ignite* or *electrify*, and English is a flexible enough language that the phrase "spark someone up" could concievably mean several different things. For example, someone could receive a flash of inspiration, a jolt of motivation, or become energized, turned on, or transformed. The words could also be slang for a literal jolt or flame, such as a flame from a lighter, or a shock from a taser.

I couldn't find a reference to tasing, but when I looked up the phrase "sparked him up" on Google books, the findings confirmed my hunch: evidently, the phrase doesn't seem to be confined to a single meaning. It can be used to mean:

#### Light Someone's Cigarette

> He made a thumb flicking motion for a light, and I **sparked him up** with my Bic. [↣](http://books.google.com/books?id=DlrBjDVdV-wC)

#### Distract, Affect, or Arouse

> The woman in the seat beside him was distracting as hell, and he needed to get his mind off her. It had been a long time since he'd met a woman who **sparked him up** like she did. In fact, as he pondered it, he wasn't sure he'd ever met a woman who affected him like she did. [↣](http://books.google.com/books?id=9X6C3Y6-aygC)

#### Energize

> Maybe the caffeine in the Cokes had **sparked him up**. [↣](http://books.google.com/books?id=wMrPPztWlWsC)

#### Motivate

> He was a rewarded with a biscuit. Tim seemed a little miffed that Teal had worked better for me than he had for him in the demonstration, justifying it by saying, ‘I think we **sparked him up** with that nicer piece of food.’ And I though we might have **sparked him up** by our remarkably quick bonding. [↣](http://books.google.com/books?id=GzCa8Fyhs0cC)

#### Inspire

> He also had that wonderful casualness of giving up on a scene if it wasn't going well. If he wasn't hap, he just mumbled fast and walked off smirking. But if he liked his material and if another actor **sparked him up**, he could fire into life. [↣](http://books.google.com/books?id=1rzZAAAAMAAJ)

It seems like the best thing to do is discern the meaning from the context where you find the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Without context, it is difficult to ascertain the exact meaning in your scenario.

Certainly, in British English, one can "spark up a cigarette", meaning to light it.  The term could be extended to mean sparking someone up as in:

> "can you spark me up please?

...although I've not heard the term used to a third party:

> Can you spark him up?

One must be careful, however, because [sparking somebody **out**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spark+out___1), means knocking somebody unconscious:

> If he doesn't shut up, I'm going to spark him out!

Answer (score 0):

to spark someone means to verbally insult them whether it be friendly or not.
EX. Billy stop talking trash before i spark you. other words with the same dictionary include: Getting someone out the way, Cooking someone, Jonin, and Flaming someone (all verbally)